# Change onclick value from different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, onclick

Need some help here. There must be a simpler way I'm not aware of. Say, I have a dynamic button that changes value based on the item that was clicked...

```
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('buy').href=this.value;"  value="http://...1.html">Product1</input>
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('buy').href=this.value;"  value="http://...2.html">Product2</input>

<a id="buy" href="#" onclick="addtocart(...)">Buy</a>
```

I understand, clicking the radio button will change the href value. My question is, is it possible to do the same on onclick? I heard it doesn't accept string like the href but a function only.

Thanks much!

Comment: Button elements can't have a href attribute. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: oops sorry my bad, should be <a> tag

Comment: You definitely can change what function is called when an element is clicked. That sort of thing is easier to do from within a script element rather than trying to do with inline attributes. You also have the option of having the `onclick="decisionFunction()"` where `decisionFunction()` would have an if/else or switch or whatever to decide which function to call next.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:radio').on('click',function(e){
            $("#buy").attr("href", e.target.value);
        })
    });
```

This function will update the value of anchors href with the value of radio button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible.

Javascript supports higher order programming, meaning you can pass around functions like any other values.

```html
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('buy').onclick=function(){alert('Radio 1')};"  value="http://...1.html">Product1</input>
<input type="radio" onclick="document.getElementById('buy').onclick=function(){alert('Radio 2')};"  value="http://...2.html">Product2</input>

<a id="buy" href="#" onclick="addtocart(...)">Buy</a>
```

This is also a good opportunity to learn about [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), with it we could also define parameters for our function.

```html
<input type="radio" onclick="var param = 'Param 1';document.getElementById('buy').onclick=function(){alert(param)};"  value="http://...1.html">Product1</input>
<input type="radio" onclick="var param = 'Param 2';document.getElementById('buy').onclick=function(){alert(param)};"  value="http://...2.html">Product2</input>

<a id="buy" href="#" onclick="addtocart(...)">Buy</a>
```

I would also recommend doing this inside a script element.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, it's very much the answer I was looking for.
The value needs to be triggered using the button.
Thanks for taking time to demonstrate. All ups to you. ;)